# sending goals at real time to a robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to send goals at real time to a robot without using rviz? (the coordinates of the goals on the map are known)
I want to write a code to get a message in the terminal like this:
'press 1 to go to (8,2)'
// (8,2) x,y is the coordinate of the goal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61826/sending-goals-at-real-time-to-a-robot/) by [basu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4791/basu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals

Have a look at the above link.I am using a similar program to send goals to the robot. Davinci  is right that you need tell us more about the setup. If you are using your own robot not a Turtlebot then you need setup navigation stack before sending goals

---

Originally posted by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) with karma: 358 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [basu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4791/basu/) on 2013-05-02**:
Yes I know this one but it is not enough to make an interface with the user. It is not turtlebot, it is my own robot.